# How to append the div at correct place in this case

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create the following HTML dynamically

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/18/

I was trying this way

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/19/

With the html i am generating , it is getting created this way

```
<div class="MyOrdersPage">
   <div class="customerNameDtl">
      <div class="customerNameDtl_left">
      MARK LITE
      </div>
      <div class="customerNameDtl_right">
         <p class="totalsection">Grand Total <span>₹ 530</span></p>
         <button class="btn btn-a">Confirm Order</button>
      </div>
      <div class="vendorNameDtsl">
         <h6>Vendor Name - TEST VENDOR</h6>
         <span>3 Items</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The issue i am facing is that the div   should not be part of div  customerNameDtl

Could you please tell me how to append the div vendorNameDtsl correctly .

Comment: please clarify *"i am facing is that the div should not be part of div customerNameDtl "* I don't understand

Comment: @DanielCheung It means that the appended div shouldn't be appended inside `customerNameDtl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append `vendorNameDtsl` to `.MyOrdersPage`:

```
 vendorNameDtsl.append(vendorhtml);
 $(".MyOrdersPage").append(customerNameDtlmain);
 $(".MyOrdersPage").append(vendorNameDtsl);
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Replace the end of your code with:

```
//customerNameDtlmain.append(vendorNameDtsl);
$(".MyOrdersPage").append(customerNameDtlmain).append(vendorNameDtsl);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".MyOrdersPage").append(customerNameDtlmain)`

Additional You must reinit jQuery mobile, by `trigger('create')`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/23/)

**Working JS:**

```
var customerNameDtlmain = $('<div class="customerNameDtl"></div>'); 
var customerNameDtl_left = $('<div class="customerNameDtl_left"></div>'); 
customerNameDtl_left.append('MARK LITE');
customerNameDtlmain.append(customerNameDtl_left);
var customerNameDtl_right = $('<div class="customerNameDtl_right"></div>'); 
var html = '<p class="totalsection">Grand Total <span>&#x20B9; 530</span></p><button class="btn btn-a">Confirm Order</button>'
customerNameDtl_right.append(html);
customerNameDtlmain.append(customerNameDtl_right);
var vendorNameDtsl = $('<div class="vendorNameDtsl"></div>'); 
var vendorhtml = '<h6>Vendor Name - TEST VENDOR</h6><span>3 Items</span>';
vendorNameDtsl.append(vendorhtml);
customerNameDtlmain.append(vendorNameDtsl);
$(".MyOrdersPage").append(customerNameDtlmain).trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will work,

```
  $("<div/>",{class:"MyOrdersPage"}).appendTo('body');
     $("<div/>",{class:"customerNameDtl"}).appendTo(".MyOrdersPage");
    $("<div/>",{class:"vendorNameDtsl"}).appendTo(".MyOrdersPage");

    $("<div/>",{class:"customerNameDtl_left",text:"MARK LITE"}).appendTo(".customerNameDtl");

    $("<div/>",{class:"customerNameDtl_right"}).appendTo(".customerNameDtl");
var html1="<p class='totalsection'>Grand Total <span>₹ 530</span></p>"+
             "<button class='btn btn-a'>Confirm Order</button>";
    $(html1).appendTo(".customerNameDtl_right");
    var html2="<h6>Vendor Name - TEST VENDOR</h6>"+
             "<span>3 Items</span>"
    $(html2).appendTo(".vendorNameDtsl");
```